# Which is better in MongoDB: multiple indexes or multiple collections

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm working on an application that authenticates users using 3rd party services (Facebook, Google, etc.). I give each user an internal id (uuid v4) which is associated with their 3rd party ids. Right now, my (mongoose) user document model looks something like this:

```
var user = new mongoose.Schema({
    uuid: {type: String, required: true, unique: true, index: true, alias: 'userId'},
    fbid: {type: String, required: false, index: true, alias: 'facebookId'},
    gid: {type: String, required: false, index: true, alias: 'googleId'}
});
```

Because I can query on any IDs, I need indexes on all of them. I'm thinking that this can become an issue with a large amount of users (or if I add more 3rd party logins (Twitter, LinkedIn, etc.). Now, my question is whether this is the correct way to do this, or if there is a better solution.

One idea I had is having multiple collections, one per ID type. Something like this:

```
var user = new mongoose.Schema({
    uuid: {type: String, required: true, unique: true, index: true, alias: 'userId'},
});

var facebookUser = new mongoose.Schema({
    fbid: {type: String, required: false, index: true, alias: 'facebookId'},
    userId: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'user'}
});
```

This has the advantage of not cluttering the user model and easier sharding, however it means more queries to retrieve a user and even more to create a new user (1. check in facebookUser collection if a user exists, if not, create a new user, save it, then create a new facebookUser with a link towards that new user and then save that).

Which way is "better" (scales well, handles load, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing to consider with indexes is that they will fix in memory. Whether you have three indexes in one collection or three collections with one index is irrelevant (as far as the index is concerned). I would lean towards putting them all into one collection for ease of use.